# Where is the placement of "all" in this sentence and why?

Tags: grammar

Where is the placement of "all" in this sentence?

> We all had better get ready to be flexible...

Comment: It's placed right after "we" and before "had".

Answer (score 1):

The "all" is from the subject, "all of us", by a rule called "q-float".  Here's a summary: [Floating quantifiers: Handle with care](http://www.bobaljik.uconn.edu/papers/FQII.pdf).  The floated quantifier can also land amongst the auxiliaries: "We had all better get ready ..."

Answer (score 1):

Both these are correct for grammar. The second is idiomatic and more broadly inclusive.

> "We all had better get ready to be flexible..."
>
> "We had all better get ready to be flexible..."

and the second elides to give:

> "We'd all better get ready to be flexible..."

Comment: Or even to "We all better get ready to be flexible. The "had" disappears completely, and  "We all" works just like "You all".